# How to import jar to java snippet node in Knime

Tags: java, import, knime

I want to import a jar file into a java snippet in Knime. I added dist.jar to the additional libraries section in the java snippet node. However, when I try import dist in the java snippet, it doesn't work and the error "The import dist cannot be resolved" occurs. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

I have already tried import dist and import dist.* and import dist.jar.

My dist.jar looks like this:

```
public class Dist {

  public double dist(double c_LON, double c_LAT) {
    // some code...
    return dist
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: I wanted to apply the method to any kind of object, so adding static to the method solved my problem.

```
public class Dist {

  public static double dist(double c_LON, double c_LAT) {
    // some code...
    return dist
  }
}
```